# Converting GeoTIFF projection definition to proj4

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, proj

I'm working with las/laz files which often have GeoTIFF information attached to them. However, for further processing I need proj4 definitions. http://spatialreference.org/ has helped me so far to convert between both manualy but ideally I'd like to do that automatically.
Is this possible somehow?

Here 2 examples of the GeoTIFF information I have and the resulting proj4 string according to spatialreference.org

GeoTIFF:

```
  reserved             43707
  user ID              'LASF_Projection'
  record ID            34735
  length after header  72
  description          'GeoTIFF GeoKeyDirectoryTag'
    GeoKeyDirectoryTag version 1.1.0 number of keys 8
      key 1024 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 1 - GTModelTypeGeoKey: ModelTypeProjected
      key 1025 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 1 - GTRasterTypeGeoKey: RasterPixelIsArea
      key 1026 tiff_tag_location 34737 count 14 value_offset 0 - GTCitationGeoKey: CH1903 / LV03
      key 2049 tiff_tag_location 34737 count 7 value_offset 14 - GeogCitationGeoKey: CH1903
      key 2054 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9102 - GeogAngularUnitsGeoKey: Angular_Degree
      key 2062 tiff_tag_location 34736 count 3 value_offset 0 - key ID 2062 not implemented
      key 3072 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 21781 - ProjectedCSTypeGeoKey: CH1903 / LV03
      key 3076 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9001 - ProjLinearUnitsGeoKey: Linear_Meter
variable length header record 2 of 4:
  reserved             43707
  user ID              'LASF_Projection'
  record ID            34736
  length after header  24
  description          'GeoTIFF GeoDoubleParamsTag'
    GeoDoubleParamsTag (number of doubles 3)
      674.4 15.1 405.3
variable length header record 3 of 4:
  reserved             43707
  user ID              'LASF_Projection'
  record ID            34737
  length after header  22
  description          'GeoTIFF GeoAsciiParamsTag'
    GeoAsciiParamsTag (number of characters 22)
      CH1903 / LV03|CH1903|
variable length header record 4 of 4:
  reserved             43707
  user ID              'liblas'
  record ID            2112
  length after header  715
  description          'OGR variant of OpenGIS WKT SRS'
```

proj4:

```
"+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=600000 +y_0=200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.4,15.1,405.3,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
```

GeoTIFF:

```
  description          'GeoTIFF GeoKeyDirectoryTag'
    GeoKeyDirectoryTag version 1.1.0 number of keys 11
      key 1024 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 1 - GTModelTypeGeoKey: ModelTypeProjected
      key 1025 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 1 - GTRasterTypeGeoKey: RasterPixelIsArea
      key 1026 tiff_tag_location 34737 count 31 value_offset 0 - GTCitationGeoKey: NAD83 / UTM zone 10N + VERT_CS
      key 2049 tiff_tag_location 34737 count 6 value_offset 31 - GeogCitationGeoKey: NAD83
      key 2054 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9102 - GeogAngularUnitsGeoKey: Angular_Degree
      key 3072 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 26910 - ProjectedCSTypeGeoKey: UTM 10 northern hemisphere
      key 3076 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9001 - ProjLinearUnitsGeoKey: Linear_Meter
      key 4096 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 5703 - VerticalCSTypeGeoKey: NAVD88 height (Reserved EPSG)
      key 4097 tiff_tag_location 34737 count 14 value_offset 37 - VerticalCitationGeoKey: NAVD88 height
      key 4098 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 5103 - VerticalDatumGeoKey: Vertical Datum Codes 5103
      key 4099 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9001 - VerticalUnitsGeoKey: Linear_Meter
variable length header record 2 of 3:
  reserved             43707
  user ID              'LASF_Projection'
  record ID            34737
  length after header  51
  description          'GeoTIFF GeoAsciiParamsTag'
    GeoAsciiParamsTag (number of characters 51)
      NAD83 / UTM zone 10N + VERT_CS|NAD83|NAVD88 height|
variable length header record 3 of 3:
  reserved             43707
  user ID              'liblas'
  record ID            2112
  length after header  951
  description          'OGR variant of OpenGIS WKT SRS'
```

proj4:

```
"+proj=utm +zone=10 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want to get the proj4 string by just specifying the EPSG code.

You can get the proj4 string with Python.

```
import urllib2
EPSG = 21781
proj4_url = 'http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/{0}/proj4/'
proj4_str = urllib2.urlopen(proj4_url.format(EPSG)).read()
print proj4_str
```

The result is

```
+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=600000 +y_0=200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

Just change the EPSG code to get another proj4 string.

Answer (score 3):

You can also directly use [pyepsg](https://github.com/rhattersley/pyepsg), A simple interface to [epsg.io](http://epsg.io/)

```py
import pyepsg
projection = pyepsg.get(21781)
pro4_str = projection.as_proj4()
print pro4_str
+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=600000 +y_0=200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.4,15.1,405.3,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
wkt_str = projection.as_wkt()
print wkt_str
PROJCS["CH1903 / LV03",GEOGCS["CH1903",DATUM["CH1903",SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7004"]],TOWGS84[674.4,15.1,405.3,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6149"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4149"]],PROJECTION["Hotine_Oblique_Mercator_Azimuth_Center"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",46.95240555555556],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",7.439583333333333],PARAMETER["azimuth",90],PARAMETER["rectified_grid_angle",90],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",600000],PARAMETER["false_northing",200000],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Y",EAST],AXIS["X",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","21781"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Python is probably best for automatic system but for temporary needs I suggest to try gdalsrsinfo http://www.gdal.org/gdalsrsinfo.html because with that you can read the the projection info directly from your images. Program supports seven formats for output:

- proj4   PROJ.4 string
- wkt   OGC WKT format (full)
- wkt_simple   OGC WKT (simplified)
- wkt_noct   OGC WKT (without OGC CT params)
- wkt_esri   ESRI WKT format
- mapinfo   Mapinfo style CoordSys format
- xml   XML format (GML based)

Example: Find proj4 definitions for image "32bit.tif"

```
gdalsrsinfo -o proj4 32bit.tif
'+proj=lcc +lat_1=36.16666666666666 +lat_2=34.33333333333334 +lat_0=33.75 +lon_0 =-79 +x_0=609601.22 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs '
```